# video in html not working in safari browser

Tags: html, video, safari

I have wordpress home page where I added video tag.
This is source code.

```
<video id="video1" width="auto" autoplay loop controls="false">
    <source src="Browser@2x.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Here, what the important is controls="false" and autoplay loop,
I want to hide controls and autoplay with looping.
It work well in chrome but not working in safari.
It weird at first I open it on safari it works but if I reopen, it doesn't.
I want to know how to solve this and if I have to use other video file type, what should I use?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
<video loop autoplay controls="true" id="video1" src='Browser@2x.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have to hide controls

Comment: If you set control="false" then i might run on iphone, but For some reason videos would not play on iPad unless you set the controls="true" flag.